# How can i reduce the response time for an API created in flask. any other way to create an API is also fine

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask, data-science, flask-restful

Below is the bare-bones structure of my code. Currently i am getting a response time between 30-40 secs which is horrible. Is there a way in which I can improve the response time drastically.

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
(some more ML libraries)

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get(self):
        Calling an external api to fetch data
        Created Machine learning model for predictions
        performed exploratory data analysis on the data retrieved through API
        return {all the necessary parameters in json}

   api.add_resource(HelloWorld,'/')
   if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.jinja_env.cache = {}
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: flask is not the issue. Flask is fine for this use case. It is the stuff you are doing when the endpoint it hit that takes so much time. You need to improve on those aspects. Calling external api and creating machine learning model. Try to measure those without flask. It will still take that long.

Comment: maybe you can invoke the "get" method during flask app booting? 

`hw = HelloWorld(Resource)
hw.get()
`
And define a new variable for the data json and save it there, and next time you invoke get method, it would already exist

Comment: It sounds a bit confusing to me as I am a beginner in all this..

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Profiler from Flask Debug Toolbar:

https://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The profiler shows how long each process takes:

https://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/panels.html#profiler